# Is there a way to export string and images from core data into cvs, which can be extracted from itunes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on the App which required functionality for fetching the saved data from core data into CVS file.
Also how we can fetch that CVS file from the iTunes onto our system ?

I can also go for SQLite if worked successfully.

I keep googling on this but not getting the desired solution which would worked correctly.

Please help me out with this, your any help will be appreciable.

Thanks